# Eclipse: How to control what shows up in your workspace?

Tags: eclipse, view, project

It provides me no value to view directories such as "`bin`", "`dist`", "`doc`" as part of my project explorer. These directories are valid and contain useful information, however i gain nothing by staring on them.

Is there a way to exclude them from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the relevant folders and files to a working set. Then tell the Package Explorer to select a Working Set, then it will only show you what you care about.

What you might want to exclude could also be filtered. All these view options are in the little upside-down triangle in the package explorer.